# If checkbox is checked then enable all input field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a trouble with enabling the input fields via a checkbox in the modal dialog. I tried using the code below but it only works with the first data in the modal. When I closed the modal and select the other user, it is not working.

**FIRST DATA**: Works fine!
[image: 1]

**SECOND DATA**: As you can see the EDIT button was enabled but the input fields is not.
[image: 2]

**SCRIPT**:

```
<script>

function enableFields() {

    var cb_edit=document.getElementById("cb_edit");

    if(cb_edit.checked) {
      document.getElementById("user_type").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("stat").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("dept").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("fname").disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("user_type").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("stat").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("dept").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("fname").disabled = true;
    }
}

</script>
```

**CHECKBOX BUTTON**:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="cb_edit" onclick="enableFields();">
<label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Edit</label>
```

**MODAL**

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-body">
            <div class="row">
              <form class="form form-vertical" method="post" action="db_user_update.php">
                <div class="form-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">User ID</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="User ID" name="u_id"
                          aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" id="u_id"  value="<?php echo $row['u_id']; ?>" readonly>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Status</label>
                        <select class="form-select el_dis" id="stat" name="stat" value="<?php echo $row['stat']; ?>" >
                          <option value="" disabled>Choose...</option>
                          <option value="0" <?php if($row['stat']==0) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Active</option>
                          <option value="1" <?php if($row['stat']==1) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Deactivated</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
                        <label for="first-name-icon">First Name</label>
                        <div class="position-relative">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control el_dis" name="fname"
                            placeholder="First Name" id="fname" value="<?php echo $row['fname']; ?>">
                          <div class="form-control-icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
                        <label for="first-name-icon">Middle Name</label>
                        <div class="position-relative">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control el_dis" name="mname"
                            placeholder="Middle Name" id="mname" value="<?php echo $row['mname']; ?>">
                          <div class="form-control-icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
                        <label for="first-name-icon">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="position-relative">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control el_dis" name="lname"
                            placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" value="<?php echo $row['lname']; ?>">
                          <div class="form-control-icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
                        <label for="first-name-icon">Suffix</label>
                        <div class="position-relative">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control el_dis" name="suffix"
                            placeholder="Suffix" id="suffix" value="<?php echo $row['suffix']; ?>">
                          <div class="form-control-icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
                        <label for="first-name-icon">Department</label>
                        <div class="position-relative">
                          <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-select el_dis" id="dept" name="dept" value="<?php echo $row['dept']; ?>">
                              <option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>
                              <option value="GS" <?php if($row['dept']=="GS") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Elementary</option>
                              <option value="JHS" <?php if($row['dept']=="JHS") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Junior High School</option>
                              <option value="SHS" <?php if($row['dept']=="SHS") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Senior High School</option>
                            </select>
                          </fieldset>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
                        <label for="first-name-icon">User Type</label>
                        <div class="position-relative">
                          <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-select el_dis" id="user_type" name="user_type" value="<?php echo $row['user_type']; ?>">
                              <option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>
                              <option value="S" <?php if($row['user_type']=="S") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Student</option>
                              <option value="E" <?php if($row['user_type']=="E") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Employee</option>
                              <option value="P" <?php if($row['user_type']=="P") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Parent</option>
                            </select>
                          </fieldset>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer  justify-content-between">
<div class="form-check form-switch">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="cbEdit" name="cbEdit" onclick="terms_changed(this)">
<label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Edit</label>
</div>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="u_id" id="u_id" value="<?php echo $row['u_id']; ?>">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-1 el_dis" id="btnUpdate" value="update" name="update">
<i class="bx bx-check d-block d-sm-none"></i>
<span class="d-none d-sm-block"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> Update</span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
<i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
<span class="d-none d-sm-block"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close</span>
</button>
<div>
</form>
```

Comment: No need to repeat code `var disabled = !document.getElementById("cb_edit").checked; document.getElementById("user_type").disabled = disabled; document.getElementById("stat").disabled = disabled;`

Comment: If you have separate modals, you cannot have more than one input on the page with the same id.

Comment: @epascarello I only use one modal for the updating and it loads with different id depends on the user.

Comment: hard to guess what your problem is with the information provided.

Comment: Do you set the checkbox back to unchecked when you set the new data?

Comment: @epascarello sorry for the lack of information, I'll edit it. No, I didn't unchecked it.

Comment: I'd make use of selectors: `let state = document.querySelector('#cb_edit').checked; document.querySelectorAll('#user_type, #stat, #dept, #fname').forEach(el => el.disabled = state)`. Even simpler if you use a class to select them.

Comment: @RobG it shorten the script but the result is still the same. It only works on the first data.

Comment: There is no modal in the OP. If you are cloning elements to create the second set of inputs, you need to give them unique IDs otherwise the function will just keep working on the first set of inputs because the selector just gets the first element with the specified ID (usually, noting that duplicate IDs are invalid in HTML). It's hard to help if you don't post code that replicates the issue.

Comment: @robG I edited the question with the modal code. I'm sorry.